# how include a "static folder" like my schema prisma in the SAM/Lambda bundler generated by esbuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, esbuild

currently my lambda definition looks like

```
  MigrateFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  FunctionName: ....
  CodeUri: ../src/
  Handler: migrate.lambdaHandler
  Timeout: 900
  Environment:
    Variables:
      DATABASE_URL: ...
Metadata:
  BuildMethod: esbuild
  BuildProperties:
    Minify: false
    Target: "es2020"
    Sourcemap: true
    EntryPoints:
    - migrate.ts
```

my project structure is like

```
-package.json
-migrate.ts
-prisma/schema.prisma
-other_files
```

now, when I execute the build I notice that it only keeps the migrate file (ts and js) but in my lambda does not show the prisma folder, my question is, how can I keep that prisma folder like a "static folder" accessible to my lambda?

thank you